# A function determining intervals of values greater than threshold

Tags: haskell

I wonder if there exists a shorter/more elegant *functional* programming way than listing all the possible cases. Here, a function that determines positions of beginning/end of subintervals greater than threshold is coded. The idea behind the listed code is to mark and retain the *beginning* of such an interval, then to push a tuple of *(beginning,ending)* as soon as the interval ends. Feel free to choose any other approach if needed.

```
-- | Determines the intervals greater than threshold.
--
-- Examples:
-- >>> intervals 0.5 [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
-- [(3,4),(8,10)]
-- >>> intervals 0.5 [1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0]
-- [(0,0),(4,5),(9,11)]
-- >>> intervals 0.5 [1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1]
-- [(0,0),(4,5),(9,11),(13,15)]
intervals :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> [(Int, Int)]
intervals threshold ys = f False 0 p
  where p = zip [0..] . map (> threshold) $ ys
        f :: Bool -> Int -> [(Int, Bool)] -> [(Int, Int)]
        f _ _ [] = []
        f True startPos ((bPos,b):[]) | b = [(startPos, bPos)]
                                      | otherwise = [(startPos, startPos)]
        f False _ ((bPos,b):[]) | b = [(bPos, bPos)]
                                | otherwise = []
        f True startPos ((aPos,a):(bPos,b):as) | a && b = f True startPos ((bPos,b):as)
                                               | a && (not b) = ((startPos, aPos)) : (f False 0 as)
                                               | otherwise = (startPos, startPos) : (f False 0 ((bPos,b):as))
        f False _ ((aPos,a):as) | a = f True aPos as
                                | otherwise = f False 0 as
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(You can skip right to **TL;DR** for a simpler approach)

Your function actually determines the *indices* of list elements that are above a threshold. In Haskell, when you have a list, an index is not the idiomatic way to represent its items. What do you want with those indices?

Agreed, your version is hard to read. For another approach, I start with

```
intervalsT :: [Bool] -> [(Int, Int]
```

and notice that the [`group`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:group) function might come in handy to collect subsequent equal elements.

```
*Main> group [True,True,False,False,True]
[[True,True],[False,False],[True]]
```

mapping `length` will result in `[2,2,1]`, which is a step closer to the indices. To turn `[a,b,c]` into `[0,a ,a+b, a+b+c]`, the function `scanl'` is perfect:

```
*Main> scanl' (+) 0 [2,2,1]
[0,2,4,5]
```

which we can `zip` with its own `tail`. But wait! We lost information whether something is above or below threshold.
zip it again with the grouped Bools, `filter` based on the bools, throw away the bools. This yields:

## TL;DR

```
intervals p = intervalsT . map (>p)
intervalsT :: [Bool] -> [(Int,Int)]
intervalsT xs = let grouped = group xs
                    idx = scanl' (+) 0 . map length $ grouped
                    ivs = zip idx (map (subtract 1) $ tail idx)
                 in map snd $ filter fst $ zip (map head grouped) ivs
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution,  Franky.

"In Haskell, when you have a list, an index is not the idiomatic way to represent its items. What do you want with those indices?"

Well, I have a directory of files each containing some voice data. I'd like to save the positions of words to a human-friendly (but also easy to parse) list. The function *intervals* works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative answer to "shorter functional programming way" would be using State monad. A possible plus of this method is preserving the same approach as in the original code while easier to comprehend. Downside of this version is its imperative/overcomplicated style.

```
import Control.Monad.State


type Result = [(Int, Int)]

check :: [Bool] -> State (Bool, Int, Int, Result) Result
check [] = do
    (started, startPos, pos, intervs) <- get
    return $ if started
      then (startPos, pos - 1) : intervs
      else intervs

check (x:xs) = do
    (started, startPos, pos, intervs) <- get
    let startPos' | x && started = startPos
                  | x = pos
                  | otherwise = -1
        intervs' | not x && started = (startPos, pos - 1) : intervs
                 | otherwise = intervs
        started' = x
    put (started', startPos', pos + 1, intervs')
    check xs

intervals :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> [(Int, Int)]
intervals threshold ys = reverse $ evalState (check ps) (False, 0, 0, [])
  where ps = map (> threshold) $ ys

main = do
  print $ intervals 0.5 [0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0]
  print $ intervals 0.5 [1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0]
  print $ intervals 0.5 [1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1]
```